# Getting a timeout in a copy data activity when connecting to a Azure Linux VM as a file source in an Azure Synapse pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I've a case where I want to transfer data from a certain platform towards our on-premise data warehouse (SQL server). This platform is a cloud based platform and can only export data based on CSV files.

To achieve this I've configured a basic Linux VM in Azure. I've made a successful connection from this platform towards this VM. So I'm able to make a connection and export the files towards it over SFTP.

From there on I want to pick up the files with a pipeline in my existing Azure Synapse environment. So I've made a copy data activity and set up the connection towards the Linux VM. This all works fine. The connection can be made and when I preview the source table it shows the data that is in there. It also sees the structure of the source and sink tables, so it automatically makes the mapping between the fields. So far so good...

The problem starts when I start the pipeline. After 5 minutes I get a timeout on connecting towards the source, which is the Linux VM. Which is quite strange, because there are no firewall settings configured on this source network. Besides that I can make a connection towards it, because the data connection can be made and the preview shows the data in just seconds.

- I've checked the firewall settings, on the Synapse workspace there are no limitations.
- I've checked the firewall settings of the Linux VM network, there are no limitations there either.
- The Synapse environment can make a connection, since the connections can be tested and it can retrieve the data for the preview function.